# One-liner if statements, how to convert this if-else-statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

Total noob here so be gentle.  I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find the answer to this.  How do I condense the following?

```
if (expression)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

I can't get it to work since it's returning something vs. setting something.  I've already seen things like this:

```
somevar = (expression) ? value1 : value2;
```

Like I said, please be gentle :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
return (expression) ? value1 : value2;
```

If `value1` and `value2` are actually `true` and `false` like in your example, you may as well just

```
return expression;
```

Comment: For clarification, this is called a "ternary operator"

Comment: I actually had it right when I tried it with "return (expression) ? value1 : value2;" but I put it right under the long way.  So, I got an error about "code unreachable" because it would never get to that statement.  Glad I asked anyway though "return expression;" makes more sense... thanks!

Comment: Actually 'Ternary' just means composed of three item, it's called a Conditional operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Joel:  Yes.  This is _the_ conditional operator.  It is _a_ ternary operator.

Comment: this throws exceptions when value1 or value2 was a function like `Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text)`

Answer (score 6):

All you'd need in your case is:

```
return expression;
```

The reason why is that the expression itself evaluates to a boolean value of `true` or `false`, so it's redundant to have an `if` block (or even a `?:` operator).

Comment: I don't think he understands _why_ so you might explain that part, but yes, this is what I would do.

Answer (score 3):

If `expression` returns a boolean, you can just return the result of it.

Example

```
 return (a > b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since expression is boolean:

```
return expression;
```